# How to PlutusTx.compile work with multiple arguments to mkPolicy

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, minting, script, policy

I'm on homework 5 of the pioneer program. If I check `Signed.hs`:

```
{-# INLINABLE mkPolicy #-}
mkPolicy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkPolicy pkh () ctx = txSignedBy (scriptContextTxInfo ctx) $ unPaymentPubKeyHash pkh

policy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy pkh = mkMintingPolicyScript $
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy . mkPolicy ||])
    `PlutusTx.applyCode`
    PlutusTx.liftCode pkh

curSymbol :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> CurrencySymbol
curSymbol = scriptCurrencySymbol . policy
```

For some reason, this works, although `mkPolicy` has 3 arguments and while compiling, there's only 1. It seems that `() -> ScriptContext` is dropped while wrapping the script (which kind a makes sense). This results in only one argument, the `PaymentPubKeyHash`.

However, when I try Homework1, I need 2 arguments, so I try this:

```
mkPolicy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkPolicy pkh deadline () ctx = 
   txSignedBy txInfo $ unPaymentPubKeyHash pkh &&
      to deadline `contains` txInfoValidRange txInfo
         where txInfo :: txInfo
               txInfo = scriptContextInfo ctx

policy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy pkh deadline = mkMintingPolicyScript $
   $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy . mkPolicy ||])
   `PlutusTx.applyCode`
   PlutusTx.liftCode pkh
   `PlutusTx.applyCode`
   PlutusTx.liftCode deadline

curSymbol :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> CurrencySymbol
curSymbol pkh deadline = scriptCurrencySymbol . policy
```

I would expect the `Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy` again drops `() -> ScriptContext` while compiling, making it using the first two `PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime`. However, when I try to compile this, I get an error:

```
src/Week05/Homework1.hs:51:56: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘ScriptContext’
      Expected type: PaymentPubKeyHash
                     -> POSIXTime -> ScriptContext -> Bool
        Actual type: PaymentPubKeyHash
                     -> POSIXTime -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
    • Probable cause: ‘mkPolicy’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘mkPolicy’
      In the Template Haskell quotation
        [|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy . mkPolicy ||]
      In the first argument of ‘PlutusTx.compile’, namely
        ‘[|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy . mkPolicy ||]’
   |
51 |    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy . mkPolicy ||])
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

So I've got the arguments wrong. I fail to understand why in the example of `Signed.hs` it works fine (1 argument to `mkPolicy`) and why it doesn't work fine in the case of 2 arguments.

What am I missing?
Thx.

== EDIT 14/02/2022

So, final solution, thanks to @Mihai Codescu

```
mkPolicy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkPolicy pkh deadline () ctx = 
   txSignedBy txInfo (unPaymentPubKeyHash pkh) &&
      to deadline `contains` txInfoValidRange txInfo
         where txInfo :: TxInfo
               txInfo = scriptContextTxInfo ctx

policy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy pkh deadline = mkMintingPolicyScript $
   $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| mintingPolicyScript ||])
   `PlutusTx.applyCode`
   PlutusTx.liftCode pkh
   `PlutusTx.applyCode`
   PlutusTx.liftCode deadline
      where 
         mintingPolicyScript :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> Scripts.WrappedMintingPolicyType
         mintingPolicyScript = \pkh' deadline' -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $ mkPolicy pkh' deadline' 

curSymbol :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> CurrencySymbol
curSymbol = \pkh' deadline' -> scriptCurrencySymbol (policy pkh' deadline')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `wrapMintingPolicy :: UnsafeFromData r => (r -> ScriptContext -> Bool) -> WrappedMintingPolicyType`.

In the first case, we can spell out the details like:

```
policy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy pkh = mkMintingPolicyScript $
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| \pkh' -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $  mkPolicy pkh' ||])
    `PlutusTx.applyCode`
    PlutusTx.liftCode pkh
```

This means we partially apply `mkPolicy` and we get something that we can apply `wrapMintingPolicy` to.

In the second case we want to have:

```
policy :: PaymentPubKeyHash -> POSIXTime -> Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy pkh deadline = mkMintingPolicyScript $
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| \pkh' deadline' -> Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy $  mkPolicy pkh' deadline' ||])
    `PlutusTx.applyCode`
    PlutusTx.liftCode pkh
    `PlutusTx.applyCode`
    PlutusTx.liftCode deadline
```

Here we can't use composition anymore: `wrapMintingPolicy :: y -> z` and `mkPolicy :: a -> b -> y`.